# Xtext - Operation

Tags: eclipse, xtext, emf

i have a question about Xtext. I know that Xtext creates a Ecore Modell for the DSL that is programmed in the .xtext File. Am i getting it right that xtext only creates EClass, EAttribute, EEnum and ERefernce in the Ecore Model? There is no way to create an Attribute of an Rule to have an EOperaption?

Comment: Well i wouldn't need it if i could get the referenced object with type and name .. of this object and the name of the reference. The latter i can get with ERerferenceObject.name... But the first is really a problem i can't collect the Object only the referenced EClass. This is example code from my dsl: setEntity=([Entity])... i can get the name of the ERerfence setEntity and i can get the EClass of the EReference and the EClass of the referenced EObject but nor the name or other information that is within the object.

Answer (score 2):

Xtext allows to import an existing EPackage or infer a new one from a grammar definition. Since EOperations are not relevant to the concrete syntax, there is nothing that could be inferred for them. If you want to use EOperations, I suggest do switch to a manually maintained, imported package.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Sebastian's answer: If you still want to use an inferred model you can use a model-postprocessor to adjust the model. This is easier if you only want to adjust only one or two things in the model like - adding *additional* operations.

Comment: Well i wouldn't need it if i could get the **referenced object with _type_ and _name_ ..** of this object and the name of the reference. The latter i can get with ERerferenceObject.name... But the first is really a problem i can't collect the Object only the referenced EClass. This is example code from my dsl: setEntity=([Entity])... i can get the name of the ERerfence detEntity and i can get the EClass of the EReference and the EClass of the referenced EObject but nor the name or other information that is within the object.

Comment: @soMasu: I'm not sure what you are talking about. But if you cannot get stuff from `Entity` when doing `xyz.getSetEntity().getAbc()` then this is a completely different story. This sounds that "resolving" did not succeed.

Comment: Simply said i have an method like compileClass(EClass o) and want to build an Template with all Attributes with its given name and types and all References with name and type. The Attributes are not the problem thats done simply with a for loop an getEAllAttributes and EAttribute.name and EAttributeType.name. But the references are the problem i dont get the information i need from them